# FMDB databaseWithPath: not writing to disk

Tags: iphone, database, cocoa, file, fmdb

The fmdb docs say that if you pass a file system path to databaseWithPath: it will create a file for you:

1. A file system path. The file does not have to exist on disk. If it does not exist, it is created for you.

I am getting my file system path with this code:

```
[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.db"];
```

And attempting to setup my db like so:

```
FMDatabase *aDB = nil;

if (aLanguageDBPath) {
        aDB = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:aLanguageDBPath];
}
```

The result is a valid FMDatabase object that isn't being written to disk as advertised. Did I misinterpret the explanation in the docs? How am I supposed to create and write dbs to disk on the fly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that the db isn't actually made on disk until `[db open];` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the NSDocumentDirectory. Change your path code with this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask,
                                                     YES);
NSString dbPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.db"];
```

Comment: Had tried that already. Still no luck. I get the db object in memory fine but I can't write it to disk.